# How to use "instead" at end of sentence

Tags: grammaticality, commas, adverbs

I'm not sure if there should be a comma after 'said' in this situation. I'm picky about punctuation and want to discover what is acceptable. Can't find any similar questions/answers. - Which (maybe both) is correct?

> She quickly said, instead, "Hello."

or

> She quickly said instead, "Hello."

Comment: Never throw stones at your mother,
You'll be sorry for it when she's dead,
Never throw stones at your mother,
Throw bricks at your father instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those example sentence look entirely natural.

I would rephrase it in one of two ways:

> She quickly said, "Hello," instead.
>   Instead, she quickly said, "Hello."

Which version would depend the context. (The style of the surrounding text, and so on.)